# Jenkins pipeline stuck on git pull origin master

Tags: jenkins

I tried to use the Jenkins pipeline but I have problems when trying to deploy. 
Here is the console output

```
Started by user Kurniawan
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /home/kurniawan/.jenkins/workspace/forway e-fleet production
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Preparation)
[Pipeline] sh
+ cd /home/kurniawan/Laravel/efleet/
+ git pull origin master
```

it just stuck there, but if i try to `git pull origin master` from command line everything just fine.
here is the pipeline instruction :

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Preparation') {
            steps {
                sh 'cd /home/kurniawan/Laravel/efleet/ && git pull origin master'
            }
        }
        stage('Testing') {
            steps {
                echo 'just testing'
            }
        }
        stage('Building') {
            steps {
                echo 'just testing'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo 'be awesome'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

anyone can help? just ask me if you need any detail, thanks.

Comment: did you compare to `jenkins` account for `git pull` and which account you use command `git pull` directly ?

Comment: I just realized that every `git pull origin master` is executed, it always asks for a passphrase key, so i change my passphrase to empty. and everything going well as is. my bad. :)